# Can A Password Be Passed As A Parameter To Your Script When Using Fake.Deploy?

Tags: deployment, parameters, passwords, f#-fake

As you all know, Fake.Deploy uses NuGet Packages for deployment to servers.  My question is, is there a way, from the command line, to call fake.deploy and pass along a password and other parameters to Fake.exe on the remote server?  I'm thinking that there would be something like this:

> fake.deploy.exe /deployRemote http://example.com:8080/fake $package --nocache password="MyP4ssw0rd"

I'd like to be able to input my password from my build server versus putting the password in my deploy script that's in the NuGet package.  The reason I need to pass along a password is because we do things like set up scheduled tasks or set different identities for app pools, which requires the username and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at Fake.Deploy's source code you can send arguments exactly as your example.
In your nuget package you need a fsx script (`setup.fsx`) where you handle the arguments.

Comment: I recall reading something like that somewhere, so it was in my mind to do that, but I couldn't find that information again due to the fact that the API reference pages have changed a bit recently.  Thank you.